# How to add html data to local storage and have it appear on a seperate html page

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have had trouble with a movie watch list project where i have two main pages (movie search page and watch list page) and one JS file they both share. I would like to be able to save a movie result after having searched for a movie on the first HTML page, and have it save to local storage and appear on the second HTML page.

I was able to create a watch list that lives on the same page as the movie search page and save selections temporarily, but when I refresh they disappeared. When I have tried saving to a separate page, I am unable to first fetch the ID where I want to insert the HTML data. I kind of understand this is because I am only able to  load one page at at time, yet I have been unable to figure out what to do about it. I have also tried to use preventDefault to stop my second HTML page from refreshing in order to see if my data is saving, but i have been unsuccessful in this as well.

Here is my java script document which both pages share

```
 function run(){
let ID

let movArr

document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener('click',async function(){
     
const movSearch = document.querySelector("#movieSearch").value

const res = await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${movSearch}&type=Movie&apikey=3c746e2`)
    const data =  await res.json()

   movArr = data.Search
    
    html=""
    for(let movie of movArr)
        {
            const rez = await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${movie.imdbID}&type=Movie&apikey=3c746e2`)
            const datatwo =  await rez.json()
            
           ID = datatwo.imdbID
           
            html +=
                   
        `       <div class="movieInput" style="display:flex;align-items:center">
                <div> 
                <img src="${movie.Poster}" style="width:99px;margin:42px 0 0 44px">
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <div style="margin:3px 0 0 21px">
                <text style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px">${movie.Title}</text>
                <p>${datatwo.imdbRating}</p>
                <div style="display:flex; gap:36px; font-size:12px"> 
                    <p>${datatwo.Runtime}</p> <p>${datatwo.Genre}</p> <p><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus" data-add="${datatwo.imdbID}"></i></p>
                </div>
                <div style="margin:-20px 0 0 0">
                    <p>${datatwo.Plot}</p>
                    
                </div> 
                </div>
                </div>
                <hr />`}
                document.querySelector("#movies").innerHTML = html
             
                })  }
                
                function watchlist(){
     localStorage.setItem( 'film' , JSON.stringify(html) )
                 document.querySelector('#moviesToo').innerHTML = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('film')) 
}
           
function watch(){   
           
   let html
document.addEventListener('click', async function(e){
   
    if(e.target.dataset.add){
console.log('clicked!')
    const movie = e.target.dataset.add
   
   const dez = await fetch(`https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${movie}&type=Movie&apikey=3c746e2`)
            const datathree =  await dez.json()
      ID = datathree.imdbID
           
          html =
                  
        `       
        <div class="movieInput" style="display:flex;align-items:center">
                <div> 
                <img src="${datathree.Poster}" style="width:99px;margin:42px 0 0 44px">
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <div style="margin:3px 0 0 21px">
                <text style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px">${datathree.Title}</text>
                <p>${datathree.imdbRating}</p>
                <div style="display:flex; gap:36px; font-size:12px"> 
                    <p>${datathree.Runtime}</p> <p>${datathree.Genre}</p> <p><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus" data-add="${datathree.imdbID}"></i></p>
                </div>
                <div style="margin:-20px 0 0 0">
                    <p>${datathree.Plot}</p>
                    
                </div> 
                </div>
                </div>
                <hr />`}
                
                    return  watchlist()     
}) 
}




run()
watch()
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.